# Adding a file under resources folder to a zip using Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have a `zip.xml` in a folder named `assembly`:

```xml
<assembly
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>archive</id>
    <baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>plugin-descriptor.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

After I build the project using `mvn clean -U -DskipTests package assembly:assembly`, I notice that only the `jar` file was copied and zipped to the archive.

How can I make the `properties` file to archived in the zip file? The wanted zip should have the jar and properties file in root

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a [`<files>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_file) element instead of a `<fileSets>` since you want to copy specific individual files and not a directory. In this case, you want to copy:

- The final JAR, so this is `${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}` into the root of the ZIP
- The properties file `src/main/resources/plugin-descriptor.properties` into the root of the ZIP

Your current configuration is wrong because you are declaring to ZIP all entries under `${project.build.directory}`, which is not what you want, since you're only interested in the final JAR. Also, using `/` as base directory is a bit weird; it would be better to say that we don't want a base directory with `<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>`

A sample configuration would be:

```xml
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>archive</id>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <files>
        <file>
            <source>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
        <file>
            <source>${basedir}/src/main/resources/plugin-descriptor.properties</source>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </file>
    </files>
</assembly>
```